# How to force CloudFormation to use specific S3 bucket if it exists or create it otherwise?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, yaml, aws-cloudformation

How to set condition in CloudFormation template that it should use a certain S3 bucket if it exists (bucket will have DeletionPolicy: Retain) or should create it if it doesn't exist.

Importing resources won't work because bucket won't be there during the first stack creation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is **no such functionality** in plain CloudFormation. The only choice is to use [custom resource](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/template-custom-resources.html).

This is a special type of resource which you have to develop yourself. This is mostly done by means of **Lambda Function**. So your template would use lambda function in the form of a custom resource to create/check if a given bucket exist or not.

Comment: When you say "no such functionality in plain CloudFormation" do you mean that there is something like that in Terraform or some other alternative solution?

Comment: @Cybex I mean, "plain" in a sense that CFN does not support it out of the box. But CFN supports `custom resources` which can provide this functionality, but you have to develop them yourself in CFN.

Comment: Yeah, I understand what you mean by plain CF but thought that maybe you also knew about whether alternative solutions like Terraform offer something like this. Thank you for your answer!

Comment: @Cybex I' not sure if TF supports it as well. But if not, I think it would be easier to make it work in TF then in CFN.

Comment: Not the automation you're looking for but you could run the template and if it fails due to the resource already existing, you could rerun it using the import resources functionality in CFN. ~ https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/resource-import.html

Comment: @George Rushby Thanks, this looks like an option. However, I think this will require too many changes to the current pipeline implementation. Might end up with a set of predefined buckets to import right away (depends on the number of buckets, though).

Comment: @Cybex ProTip: Make sure you add `DeletionPolicy: Retain` to any resources that you want to import; otherwise you might end up deleting a running resource due to an error in your templates.

Comment: @George Rushby Yeah, definitely, I mentioned this policy in my original post.